# SQL71501 Adding a Role Membership in SSDT VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to add a role membership with my SSDT database project.

```
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'<RoleName>', @membername = N'<Domain>\svc.data'
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL71501: Role Membership: <unnamed> has an unresolved reference to object [<Domain>\svc.data]
```

The user and logins are defined and if I switch the code to another user ie:

```
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'<RoleName>', @membername = N'<Domain>\svc.data2'
```

It works perfectly.

I have reimported the schema from the live database (the live database works fine) and I get the same error.

Comment: Hi Alina,

I did the same thing. Added the roles and security in a post deployment script. Not ideal. But it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out what you can try. But make sure you have latest SSDT power tools installed:

1) Create a folder like Security

2) Right-click, then Add -> New Item

3) Under SQL Server -> Security

There is a Server Role type file and Server Role Membership.
Let me know if that helps.

I used that to create the Database Role, moved out the scripts out of the post-deploy and it all worked well. I was also granting the permissions in the same file, just had to use GO separator after each line.